# Why both the processes(parent & child) point to same code and data segment?

Tags: c, process

I tried to create a child process using fork() and tried to check the code and data segment of child process. But both the processes point to same location.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

static int global_var = 10;

void increment(int *var){
        printf("Incrementing @%p\n", var);
        *var += 1;
}

void decrement(int *var){
        printf("Decrementing @%p\n", var);
        *var -= 1;
}

void do_operation(void (*my_ops)(int *)){

        my_ops(&global_var);
        printf("@Adr=0x%p, Global Val = %d\n", &global_var, global_var);
}


int main(){

        int i, local_var;
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        switch(pid){

                case -1:
                        printf("Failed to create new Process.\n");
                        break;
                case 0:
                        printf("Calling do_operation(), which is @%p\n", &do_operation);
                        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                                printf("Child Process with pid(%d), ", getpid());
                                do_operation(&decrement);
                                sleep(1);
                        }
                        break;

                default:
                        printf("Calling do_operation(), which is @%p\n", &do_operation);
                        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                                printf("Parent Process with pid(%d), ", getpid());
                                do_operation(&increment);
                                sleep(1);
                        }
                        wait(NULL);
                        break;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The code segment and data segment of both processes point to same address. You can see the following output.

```
Calling do_operation(), which is @0x55d37fd34846
Parent Process with pid(2718), Incrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 11
Calling do_operation(), which is @0x55d37fd34846
Child Process with pid(2719), Decrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 9
Parent Process with pid(2718), Incrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 12
Child Process with pid(2719), Decrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 8
Parent Process with pid(2718), Incrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 13
Child Process with pid(2719), Decrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 7
Parent Process with pid(2718), Incrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 14
Child Process with pid(2719), Decrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 6
Parent Process with pid(2718), Incrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 15
Child Process with pid(2719), Decrementing @0x55d37ff35010
@Adr=0x0x55d37ff35010, Global Val = 5
```

You can see the address of static variable in both processes are same. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

On most modern operating systems, every process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Therefore, even if two processes share the same virtual memory address, this does not mean that these virtual addresses are mapped to the same **physical** memory address.

When forking a process, the mapping of the virtual memory pages to the physical memory pages probably stays the same, except that [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) is activated for all of the memory pages. That way, if one process changes a memory page, both processes get their own copy of that memory page in physical memory. In that case, the virtual memory addresses in both processes will stay the same, but the physical memory addresses will be different.